# Pilcrow question

Tags: typography, symbols

Is there a difference between a shaded and an unshaded pilcrow? I am trying to format a block letter and in the unarranged copy, I am supposed to correct- there are both unshaded and shaded pilcrows.

Comment: When I google [**unshaded and shaded pilcrows**](https://www.google.com/search?q=unshaded+and+shaded+pilcrows&oq=unshaded+and+shaded+pilcrows&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I don't immediately find anything that tells me what exactly you're asking about here. Are you perhaps asking about any significance as to whether the "loop" is [**filled or unfilled**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow)? Personally I doubt it, but you can read that Wikipedia article yourself to find out more.

Comment: Yes, I mean is there a big difference as to whether the pilcrow is filled or unfilled. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Cristina No, there is no difference. They’re just graphical variants, like a and ɑ or g and ɡ – some fonts have one, some have the other. As such, this isn’t related to English; it’s the same for all languages.

Comment: I'm sure it makes a difference with musical notes (quavers, crochets, breves), but I can't remember and can't be bothered to look up *what* that difference is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The ones with the filled heads are shorter, there's only one with an unfilled head and a tail (the minim) which is shorter than a semibreve which is shorter than a breve. The last two are open and have no tails. This is not like the filled pilcrow because the filled and unfilled notes are inherently different, a little like different letters.

Comment: @BoldBen: Ah, right - that makes sense to me. I actually had half an idea that a "filled in" symbol might have meant ***to be played louder*** - which seemed logical to me, given ***bold typeface*** implies "emphasis". But ***"filled in" = bold = emphatic = longer*** seems an equally obvious / intuitive connection, so I'm sure I'll find the "music symbol" significance easy to remember now, thanks. In principle, I could imagine using "bold" pilcrows for "more significant" paragraph breaks (maybe followed by a double rather than single blank line), but I know little of typographic conventions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've got them the wrong way round, the filled in notes are shorter and the open ones longer. I think it's because the long ones came first and were drawn open. The semibreve has no stem and is open, the minim is open and has a plain stem, it's half a semibreve. The crotchet has a filled head and a plain stem, it's is half a minim. The quaver has a filled head and a stem with one tail, it's is half a crotchet. A semiquaver has a filled head and a stem with two tails, it's half a quaver and so on. Have fun.

Comment: @BoldBen: Aw dammit! That makes even more sense now! I did think it was a bit odd that I didn't confidently *know* how it works for musical notation. Obviously the actual convention as implemented is "counter-intuitive" to me - but I find many things like this *are* intuitive, so I don't need to bother remembering them at all (I'll always make the right "guess" if I need the information). So I'll just have to file this particular one under *Contexts where my intuition is **wrong*** (which knowledge will unerringly lead me to the ***right*** answer! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is internally logical but anyone learning music has to learn the conventions (and a whole heap of other stuff as well). Glad to have been of some assistance!

Answer (score 2):

#### No.

This is a matter of style/font.

> The pilcrow is usually drawn similar to a lowercase q reaching from descender to ascender height; **the loop can be filled or unfilled.**

There is evidence that an unfilled loop was used in the original character, looking somewhat like this: **⸿**.

Over time, the pilcrow evolved to become aligned and the loop *was* filled in standard practise:

> ...the symbol *[loop]* was filled in with dark ink and eventually looked like
> the modern pilcrow (¶).

However, even though a filled pilcrow is the most common form, this does not mean an unfilled pilcrow is incorrect.  As I have mentioned, it's a matter of style.  Take your pick!

[Quotes from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow#cite_note-11)

[image: pilcrows]

Comment: You say "take your pick", but isn't this really a matter of ***which font you choose**?* I don't know much about these things, but surely any given font would include one or the other (not both) - same as with **a / ɑ** and **g / ɡ** as pointed out by @Janus above. In which case the type of pilcrow you get might effectively be predetermined by other choices you already made for other reasons.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 99% of keyboards do not include the pilcrow.  Most people will copy and paste the pilcrow from the Internet.  When they paste it into say a Word document, the pilcrow will format in the font used when it was copied.  Therefore if you want an unfilled pilcrow symbol, copy and paste the unfilled pilcrow and it will render this way regardless of the font you are inputting with.

Comment: But @janus above says the type of pilcrow you get depends on the ***font*** you're using. Surely if you cut&paste an example from the Internet (or enter the Unicode value directly, if your OS / WP allows), that wouldn't override what the current active font looked like for this character?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If this is what Janus has said, I am afraid he is mistaken.  If you cut+paste from the Internet, it will override the current font, _unless_ you paste without formatting (Ctrl+Shift+V).  But this diverts from the point.  `paste-without-formatting` is very uncommon; you can still pick your pilcrow by pasting normally